# How to allow a single url but restrict the others using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, webserver, apache, vhosts

I am trying to allow  a single location (a **file which does not exist**) to be accessed on my Apache 2.2.3 (Centos) server to be able to implement the paypal ipn listener.
The other files should stay password protected.

**How can I allow a single location to be accessed without login?**

The code bellow shows what I tried so far.

The location directive selects the correct location (I tested this by writing deny from all to it).

The **issue I have** now is that the **server is still asking for a password for that location**.

I tried already to put the location directive into the directory one but this leads to an syntax error (even if it would be allowed for file directives) but I **can not use a file directive** instead a location one, because the file does not physically exist.

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.net/subdomains/p103.myproject/httpdocs/public>
Order Deny,Allow
 Options -Includes -ExecCGI
 SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
 AuthName "myproject"
 AuthType Basic
 AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.net/subdomains/p103.myproject/.htpasswd
 AuthGroupFile /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.net/subdomains/p103.myproject/.htgroups
 Require group myproject
</Directory>
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.net/subdomains/p103.myproject/httpdocs/public
<Location "/ipn/sdsad8329ejslkdjasl">
 Order Deny,Allow
 Allow from all
 Satisfy Any
</Location>
```

Here a link to the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `SetEnvIf` to match against the Request_URI to set a variable, then use a combination of `Satisfy any`, `Require group myproject` and `Allow`.

Try something like this:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.net/subdomains/p103.myproject/httpdocs/public

# Here we check if the request is for something we don't need to authorize
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/ipn/sdsad8329ejslkdjasl NO_AUTH_NEEDED=1

<Directory /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.net/subdomains/p103.myproject/httpdocs/public>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Options -Includes -ExecCGI
  SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
  AuthName "myproject"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.net/subdomains/p103.myproject/.htpasswd
  AuthGroupFile /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.net/subdomains/p103.myproject/.htgroups

  # This makes it so one of the 2 is good enough
  Satisfy Any
  # We allow first, but only if the NO_AUTH_NEEDED is set
  Allow from env=NO_AUTH_NEEDED
  # Otherwise, require a login
  Require group myproject

</Directory>
```

Comment: I tested your script. it is valid syntax (accpted by httpd) but a password is still required.
I do not understand how you use the env variable in the directory directive.

Comment: I made the same test as in my previous setup. I wrote now Deny from ... where you had Allow but the server still asked for a password this could mean the env variable is not set as expected. what do you think?

Comment: look we have written there SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

Comment: This is solved now I changed his line to the following: SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/ipn/1267hskdjskd987eusd62tas$" NO_AUTH_NEEDED=1

Comment: I found this site very useful: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/allow-single-url/